# JS see if any child input is empty

Tags: javascript

```
var valid = false;
        $("#f1 input").each(function () {
            if($.trim($(this).val()) != 0) {
                valid = true;
            }
        });
        console.log(valid);
```

Above code is supposed to check all inputs inside of #f1, and if any is empty it shall print false. But now it only requires that one of every child input has a value to print true.

How may I fix this?

Comment: Can you please be more detail in what  you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would invert your logic so that `valid` is only updated when something fails.

```
var valid = true;
$("#f1 input").each(function () {
    if($.trim($(this).val()) == 0) {
        valid = false;
    }
});
console.log(valid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.you could assign the false statement in else condition .If first one is `true` valid is replaced by true but not get the `false`.Because valid false only initially declared not inside the each function .so you could add else .

```
if ($.trim($(this).val()))
```

Its only enough to find a empty or not

```
var valid = false;
$("#f1 input").each(function() {
  if ($.trim($(this).val())) {
    valid = true;
  } else {
    valid = false;
  }
});
console.log(valid);
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition(`$.trim($(this).val()).length != 0`) would only fail when the input is `0`, instead you need to check the `length` property of the trimmed value.

```
if($.trim($(this).val()).length != 0){
  //.....
}

// or simply check the length property, since 0 is falsy value 
// and all other integers are truthy
if($.trim($(this).val()).length){
  //.....
}
```

---

Or another way by filtering non-empty inputs using [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```
var valid = $("#f1 input").filter(function () {
   return $(this).val().trim().length;
}).length > 0;

console.log(valid);
```